# SQL Duplication across 2 fields

Tags: sql

I have several fields in a table, but wish to remove some records. I'll call them duplicates, but they aren't in the true sense.

The table and some example data

```
Id1  Id2  Name1  Name2  DOB1      DOB2 
123, abc, jones, smith, 19740901, 19820101
abc, 123, smith, Jones, 19820101, 19740901
def, 456, davis, short, 19720101, 20011010
456, def, short, davis, 20011010, 19720101
```

What I want to do is remove one of each of the "duplicate" records as its just the same as the other, but with "1 columns" transposed with the "2 columns". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear.  For the data you showed, what is the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a standard SQL way of doing this:

```
delete from t
    where Id1 > Id2 and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.Id1 = t.Id2 and
                        t2.Id2 = t.Id1 and
                        t2.Name1 = t.Name2 and
                        t2.Name2 = t.Name1 and
                        t2.DOB1 = t.DOB2 and
                        t2.DOB2 = t.DOB1
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `INNER JOIN` to pair up any rows with transposed `Id1` and `Id2` values, filter down to those that are actually duplicates, select all but one of the duplicate rows, and then send the results to a `DELETE`.

```
DELETE T1
FROM [TableName] T1
-- Pair up the duplicate rows
INNER JOIN [TableName] T2
    ON  T1.Id1 = T2.Id2
    AND T1.Id2 = T2.Id1
WHERE T1.Id1 > T1.Id2 -- Only delete the row with the higher "Id1" value
-- Filter out any rows that are not actually duplicates
AND   T1.Name1 = T2.Name1
AND   T1.Name2 = T2.Name2
AND   T1.Name2 = T2.Name2
AND   T1.DOB1  = T2.DOB1
AND   T1.DOB2  = T2.DOB2
```

Answer (score 0):

delete from test
where id1 in(
  select a.id1
  from test a inner join test b on a.id1 = b.id2 and a.id2 = b.id1 and a.id1 < b.id1)

It is important to note that this code will not delete records where id1 = id2.